# Comparing strings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to compare urls in mysql but the query returns results matching any url.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT
  a.comment_ID, 
  a.comment_post_ID, 
  a.comment_content, 
  a.comment_date_gmt,  
  a.comment_author_url, 
  b.post_title, b.ID
 FROM 
   `wp_comments` a, 
   `wp_posts` b
 WHERE 
   a.comment_post_ID = b.ID
  AND 
   ('a.comment_author_email' = '$email'
   OR 
    'a.comment_author_url' = '$url')
  AND a.comment_approved = 1
 GROUP BY a.comment_ID
 ORDER BY a.comment_ID DESC
```

Thanks!

edit: [full query](http://pastebin.com/QJmPfd0e)

Comment: Consider revising this condition 
**AND ('a.comment_author_email' = '$email'                                        
OR 'a.comment_author_url' = '$url')** 
This returns true for either the author's email or the URL provided. What values are you passing?

Comment: if possible, send us this query with values and not variables, will make it easier to help =)

Comment: Here is almost the full code... http://pastebin.com/QJmPfd0e

Answer (score 2):

In your query, make sure you replace all the `'` (single quote) characters with the `` ` `` (backtick) character.

Answer (score 0):

**Tips:**

- Remove `'` around php variable
- Write backticks  <kbd>`</kbd> around table attributes instead of <kbd>'</kbd>
- may be use of `INNER JOIN` can make thing easier

TRY this

```
$qry = " SELECT { watever} FROM  `wp_comments` a,
         INNER JOIN  `wp_posts` b ON `a`.`comment_post_ID` = `b`.`ID`
         WHERE
              `a`.`comment_author_email` = '".$email."'   
          OR  `a`.`comment_author_url` ='". $url."'     
         GROUP BY `a`.`comment_ID`
         ORDER BY `a`.`comment_ID` DESC ";
```

Comment: Same result. Just returns any rows with a url in the comment_author_url :/